# How to Hide a category title or description at wordpress using jquery or css?

Tags: php, javascript, css, wordpress

How to Hide a category title or description at wordpress using jquery or css?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please consider improving your question. Your question in its current form does not contain enough details. Please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) and the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) section on ways to improve your question.

Answer (score 2):

apply `display:none` to the element.

if the category title was

```
    <h3 class="single_cat_title">Title here</h3>
```

You would add

```
    .single_cat_title {display:none;}
```

In jQuery,
use the selector.hide() function.

```
    $('.single_cat_title').hide();
```

Please provide more details in your problem next time, it will help us, to help you!